# How can I improve the accuracy of a DEM using surveyed points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, accuracy

I have a DEM and many surveyed points in the area. The survey points have centimeter accuracy. The difference between the DEM to the actual height ranges from -20cm to +20cm. It is not a uniform offset.
Can I somehow "stretch" or "rubbersheet" the DEM using the surveyed points in order to improve its accuracy? I can use ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro, or QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be fooled into thinking that you are improving the accuracy of your data.  The only 'accurate' data would be the survey points themselves.  You apparently do not know anything about the quality of the elevation values in areas that are not coincident with a survey points.  Still, if you want to proceed to make up data you could.

1. Use your survey points to interpolate a new surface.
2. Subtract the original DEM from the survey interpolated surface to determine the difference between the original DEM and the survey surface.
3. Subtract from the original DEM the difference surface.

For any pixel on a survey point the elevation at that pixel should now be the same as the survey point elevation (or close to depending on your interpolation method).